# Не могу послать локальный запрос из моего js файла в node js оба на моем компе

Tags: javascript, node.js

Не могу послать локальный запрос из моего js файла в node js оба на моем компе , вот как я это делаю 
вот node js

```
var http=require('http');
var model={name:"aaaavava"}
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   response.end(JSON.stringify(model));
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

а вот как на него посылаю запрос

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="loadPhones()" id="button">Загрузить json!</button>
 <script>
    function loadPhones() {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/', true);
      xhr.send();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
       button.innerHTML = 'Готово!';

        if (xhr.status != 200) {
          alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
        } else {
          alert(xhr.responseText);
            document.write(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
         }

      button.innerHTML = 'Загружаю...';
      button.disabled = true;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

получаю такую ошибку

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8081/: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8888' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

хотя через браузер работает nodejs файл

Comment: Использовать `XMLHttpRequest` напрямую в 2018 о_О

Comment: Да хоть телегами перевозил бы свой ajax, в чем проблема ? :) Предложите же вариант лучше, чем делать большие глаза.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю что вы при заходе на свою локальную страницу набираете http://localhost:8888 , однако хотите чтоб сервер на адресе 127.0.0.1 корректно принимал ваши аякс запросы.

Строго говоря localhost и 127.0.0.1 как доменное имя - не одно и то же.

Тут либо заходите на 127.0.0.1 либо запускайте оба сервера на localhost.

Можете забуриться в эту тему прочитав вот [этот](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) документ.